# How to access (in large scale, not just searching several results) the database of the web of science?

Tags: database, dataset, web-crawler, citations

I am doing research which needs large scale citation data. I would like to access the database of web of science. For example, I may want the citations of all the papers published in Nature in 2013. How can I get such a dataset? Do the web of science open the database to users? Or do I need to somehow crawl the data myself? Any suggestion is appreciated. T

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Citations, off-line, in your own computer, you must Crawl the data and store. To Crawl the data, I suggest the Apache Tika: "The Apache Tika™ toolkit detects and extracts metadata and text content from various documents - from PPT to CSV to PDF - using existing parser libraries" - from the Tika website [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/).

Talking on a large scale, I think this is the best method because once downloaded, it will be at your computer to perform many searches you want without having to wait for the search to be completed due to the latency of a remote search